# Polymorphic, many-to-one relationships in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I am having some trouble wrapping my head around how to structure this, as it seems to be the "inverse" of all of the Laravel documentation and other examples I've found. I'm probably over-thinking it.

All of the examples I've found assume that you have one fixed datatype (e.g. `Comment`) that can then be attached to any number of different 'owners'. In my case, I want to have one 'owner' that can then be related to an arbitrary number of different types.

Consider a situation where:

- We begin with an `Entity`
- An `Entity` can have any number of `Components`
- `Components` can be one of two or three dozen different possible types, each holding their own data (in their own database table), but with a common accessor interface
- A given `Entity` may have 0 components, 1 components, or 24 components

We will want to be able to retrieve an `Entity`, enumerate its `Component`s, and access them.

I think I have the right database schema, but cannot figure out how to craft the classes.

```
        Schema::create('entities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            /* ... other boring stuff */

            $table->timestamps();
        });

       Schema::create('components_entities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->foreignIdFor(Entity::class);
            $table->string('component_type');
            $table->foreignId('component_id');

            $table->timestamps();
        });

        /* Example of type of component - class App\Models\Components\HaaProperties */
        Schema::create('ecd_propbag', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->json('bag');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        /* Example of type of component - class App\Models\Components\IsRecoverable */
        Schema::create('ecd_recoverable', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('recovery_time');
            $table->integer('recovery_cost');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Given this structure, how do I set up the relations at the class level?

Comment: I think you need to use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-model-structure . Also are you planning to make tables for each of those components? That sounds very cumbersome and restrictive.

Comment: @Flame It's a trade-off... One huge table (potentially 10m rows) vs splitting it out, where a load of 'everything' will either require many joins or many separate queries. We'll see  how it optimizes out on queries...

Comment: Yea 10m is a lot, but not too much with proper indexing. It all depends on what specific queries you want to do with it. Separating your components into multiple tables vs a single table with a `component_type` column, shouldnt logically make a difference if you just index that `type` column. But then again that single table might contain a lot of NULL values if your components require widely different columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, an Entity can have many Components and Components are of many types

```
//Component Model
public function type()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Components\Type');
}
public function entity()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Components\Entity');
}



//Entity Model
public function components()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Components');
}
```

To retrieve components of an Entity

```
Entity::all()->first()->components()
```